# Connection to EC2 AWS refused without changes and rebooting/re-starting instance doesn't work

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I searched around for answers here and in AWS forums and nothing helped.

Tried creating a new .pem file, tried rebooting the instance, tried stopping and restarting the instance. Nothing seems to work.

The connection was working perfect and no changes were made.

We are having some issues connecting to our instance. Was working fine and suddenly stopped.

No changes done. I tried rebooting the instance and stopping and starting the instance and nothing has helped.

Here is the log of the terminal

```
MacBook-Pro:pem $ ssh -vv -i '/XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem'
ec2-user@<ip address> OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.7
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ip address> [<ip address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 52.26.48.45:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent Connection closed by <ip address>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Seems like amazon doesn't provide any support unless you pay...

Comment: Looks like the key file you are trying to use doesn't exist on the computer you are running the ssh command on...

Comment: It does exist. It used to work using exactly the same pem file and same location, same code. Don't know why it suddenly changed.

Comment: Please show results of: `ls -l /XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem`

Comment: -rw-------@ 1 MACBOOK  staff  1696 Nov 20 10:34 /XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem

Answer (score 0):

@mbaird give the clue, something changed some hours ago (depending on your TZ) Your pem file has been modified on **Nov 20 10:34**

```
-rw-------@ 1 MACBOOK staff 1696 Nov 20 10:34 /XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem
```

Comment: Yes. I created a new PEM to see if that solved the problem. Issue is the same. Connection closed.

Comment: To be sure your pem file is OK compare your fingerprint key:

`ec2-fingerprint-key ./XXX/pem/FILENAME.pem`

with the fingerprint you see in the key pair associated to the instance in AWS. They must match.